# Compiling a kernel

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to do a make menuconfig and came across these two requirements:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential (read that 'make' will be installed)


sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev flex bison openssl libssl-dev dkms libelf-dev libudev-dev libpci-dev libiberty-dev autoconf (from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel#:~:text=obtain%20the%20sources.-,apt%2Dget,%2Dimage%2D%24(uname%20%2Dr))
```

Do I need to run those two commands or the second one will do?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic. You may be able to get help on our sister sites, [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ll need to run both commands. The first installs the compiler and related tools (needed to compile *anything*), the second one installs certain tools and libraries needed in the process of configuring and compiling *the kernel specifically*.

Answer (score -1):

Check out this utility, it helped me too: https://github.com/mtompkins/linux-kernel-utilities